# Ionic - disable animation for nav bar

Tags: android, ionic-framework, navbar

My app has a static header. Meaning it remains the same in all views.
The problem is that when I use the `<ion-nav-bar>` directive the header is animated every time the view changes.
On IOS it's not that bad because the entire is sliding in, but on Android it looks like it flickers.

How can I disable the animation entirely?
I already tried using `$ionicConfigProvider.navBar.transition('none');` in the `app.config` section, but it actually made it worse (also flickers on IOS).

I created a simple [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QywzaE) (the default transition appears to that of IOS, but if you open the developer console on chrome and change to an android device you can see the flickering).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you really no idea to how solve this.

you can modify the transition function

First, in `app.config` section

```
$ionicConfigProvider.navBar.transition('android');
```

then, modify ionic transition function

```
$ionicConfigProvider.transitions.navBar.android = function(enteringHeaderBar, leavingHeaderBar, direction, shouldAnimate) {
    function setStyles(ctrl, opacity) {
        if (!ctrl) return;
        var css = {};
        // ionic original
        // css.opacity = opacity === 1 ? '' : opacity;

        // modify
        if (opacity === 1) {
            css.opacity = '';
            css.display = '';
        } else {
            css.opacity = opacity;
            css.display = 'none'; // let leavingHeaderBar immediately disappear
        }

        ctrl.setCss('buttons-left', css);
        ctrl.setCss('buttons-right', css);
        ctrl.setCss('back-button', css);
        ctrl.setCss('back-text', css);
        ctrl.setCss('title', css);
    }

    return {
        run: function(step) {
            setStyles(enteringHeaderBar.controller(), step);
            setStyles(leavingHeaderBar && leavingHeaderBar.controller(), 1 - step);
        },
        shouldAnimate: shouldAnimate && (direction == 'forward' || direction == 'back')
    };
};
```

Comment: very nice!
I actually thought about changing the source code, but I didn't want to do it because it would have just got overridden on the next update. Didn't think about overriding the function itself in my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ionic 2 or higher, use the following CSS only:

```
.toolbar{
    .title, button{
        opacity: 1!important;
        transform: none!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this in my app.scss and it worked like a charm :D